# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Home isEqualToString:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, uipickerview

I am fetching data from a web service:

```
//temp1 is NSDictionary
//responseArr1 is NSMutableArray
for(temp1 in responseArr1)......., 
{
     quesTxt = [[temp1 objectForKey:@"question_text"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%PROFILENAME%" withString:del.onlyFirstName];

     quesID = [temp1 objectForKey:@"idlife_stage_question"];

     Home *objHome=[[Home alloc] init];

     objHome.homeQuesTxt = quesTxt;
     objHome.homeQuesID = quesID;

     [quesArray addObject:objHome];

     //[quesArray addObject:[[temp1 objectForKey:@"question_text"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%PROFILENAME%" withString:del.onlyFirstName]];//this works fine

        }
```

All the date when i try to populate in picker view it gives exception.

picker view delegate:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *retval = (id)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    }

    retval.text = [quesArray objectAtIndex:row];.........// **EXCEPTION HERE**...

    retval.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    retval.numberOfLines = 3;

    return retval;
}
```

sample of my web service:

```
{
        "idlife_stage_question" = 35;
        "life_stage_idlife_stage" = 1;
        "profile_idprofile" = 0;
        "question_text" = "When %PROFILENAME% first smiled?";..//%PROFILENAME% replaces with user name which i have
        sequence = 34;
    }
```

**Home is a subclass of NSObject**

Please help.

Comment: Put break point to your code and trace correct crashing point ? Show crash code to us...

Comment: your Label.text is a string and you are assigning it an object.

Comment: i agree with @nsgulliver

Comment: @nsgulliver: even i agree, that is what i just answered :)

Comment: i have already mentioned that retval.text = [quesArray objectAtIndex:row];.........// **EXCEPTION HERE**...

Comment: -[Home isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaea37e0
2013-04-23 16:30:33.070 Kangatime[2145:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Home isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaea37e0'

Comment: try `retval.text = [[quesArray objectAtIndex:row] homeQuesTxt]; `

Comment: Hey Anoop, this helped me but i also need to insert a custom row in array which would be displayed everytime at the end of aray..how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
retval.text = [quesArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Here you are accessing `quesArray`.

Which is as : `[quesArray addObject:objHome];`

And objHome is : `Home *objHome=[[Home alloc] init];`

So you error is here, you tried to put the object into the `retval` which expects an `NSString`.

**You need to use something as :**

```
retval.text = [[quesArray objectAtIndex:row] homeQuesTxt]; //or anyother property that you want to show in text
```

Comment: Hey Anoop, this helped me but i also need to insert a custom row in array which would be displayed everytime at the end of aray..how can i do that?

Comment: @user2268539: what is custom row in array? do you want to add some text there?

Comment: Yes...like "Create your own question"

Comment: but i am displaying data in picker using [[quesArray objectAtIndex:row] homeQuesTxt]??

Comment: uipicker is view, you need to add in the model.

Answer (score 1):

```
retval.text = [quesArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Your `retval.text` is a string and you are assigning it an object

You could do like this

```
 Home  *newHome=[quesArray objectAtIndex:row];

  retval.text=newHome.homeQuesTxt;
```

Comment: Thanks, now  it displays data but when i scroll picker it throws another exception:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString homeQuesTxt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e72a8

Comment: here..retval.text=newHome.homeQuesTxt;

Comment: Check how you defining homeQuesTxt.

Comment: like this in Home class..@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *homeQuesTxt;

Comment: You should debug your code or set breakpointer, try to cast the value to (NSString*) before assigning. Also check your label is not deallocated.

Comment: Also try to print the same text in `NSLog` only and see if it gives you error?

Answer (score 0):

The `quesArray` is populated with `Home` Objects

```
Home *home = quesArray[row];
retval.text = home.homeQuesTxt;
```